# Is it possible to initialize `List` with a value on method call

Tags: java, list, arguments

below is a method with argument of type `List`

```
 void addToMe(List<String> list)
```

is it possible to pass value like this

```
 addToMe(new ArrayList<String>().add("Test Element"));
```

Right now giving me error `incompatible types: boolean cannot be converted to List<String>`. Why it is not allowed ?

Comment: It's not allowed because `boolean cannot be converted to List<String>`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis It should return a `List` object, I don't understand why it says `boolean`

Comment: Tell us why you think the expression `new ArrayList<String>().add("Test Element")` should return a `List` object?

Comment: [The `.add()` method of a `List` returns a `boolean`, not a `List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add-E-)...

Comment: If you specifically want an ArrayList<String> or a subtype you can use an anonymous type with an initialiser block.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason you can't do `addToMe(new ArrayList<String>().add("Test Element"));` is because `add(E)` isn't designed for [fluent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface) style programming: it [returns a `boolean`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add(E)), not the original list with an added element.

#### Option 1: Anonymous type with initializer block*

```
new ArrayList<String>(){{ add("Test Element"); }}
```

In your code:

```
void addToMe(new ArrayList<String>(){{ add("Test Element"); }})
```

This is **read+write** and still a `List<String>` so you can treat it as such without problems, (warning: there are subtle consequences to this, as the type returned by `getClass()` on that list won't be `java.util.ArrayList` now, it will instead be an anonymous class type).

#### Option 2: use the (dangerous) `Arrays.asList(String... args)`

Alternatively if you only need a `List<String>`, and it doesn't need to be writeable you could use [`Arrays#asList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...)). But: **be careful**. This is a **fixed size list**. Adding more items to it will throw an `UnsupportedOperationException`:

```
void addToMe(Arrays.asList("Test Element1", "Test Element2"));
```

#### Option 3: use the JCF "copy" constructor

In [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#optional-restrictions) for `Collection<E>` in the JCF, it states:

> All general-purpose Collection implementation classes ... should provide ...  a constructor with a single argument of type Collection, which creates a new collection with the same elements as its argument.

Therefore, if you use this with `Arrays.asList(String... args)`, you can do:

```
    void addToMe(new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("Test Element1", "Test Element2")));
```

But this is ugly and hard to read, so I recommend splitting it up into more than one line. The advantage over just using `Arrays.asList` is that it is read+write and not fixed size.

Answer (score 0):

> addToMe(new ArrayList().add("Test Element"));

The `.add()` method of a `List` is inherited from `Collection`, and by definition it does not return the `Collection` itself but a `boolean`; therefore this can't work.

You can, however, do:

```
addToMe(Arrays.asList("Test Element"));
```

The Java compiler will never "automagically" walk the method call chain and deduce your intents; it is pretty "dumb".

But on the other hand, everybody has different intents; this is why languages have rules... And languages which are too "liberal" often are hard to read.

As one of the Java core specification writer once said: "You write code only once; you read it many times".

Comment: This should come with a **big health warning**: trying to add to the returned `List` from `Arrays.asList` throws an `UnsupportedOperationException` as the list is fixed size

Comment: @AndyBrown yup, but here the `Arrays.asList()` is an argument. I don't believe the OP tries and modifies the argument, but yeah, you never know

Comment: Not a criticism, just a strong health warning that is worth stating. It wasn't specified as a read-only list in the OP's question, it was just a method signature parameter.

Answer (score -1):

your call to "add(Element)" returns true on success or false on failure.  It's a boolean function.  Instead, use:

```
addToMe(new ArrayList<String>(new String[]{"Test Element"}));
```

Answer (score -1):

You are passing a `boolean` into your function, because that is what `List.add()` returns. You can see the Java documentation for `List.add()` here:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add(E)